# Metapost to tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, algorithms, metapost

We can a document that explain how we can write scratch algorithm in latex [mp-scratch](https://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/G/mp-scratch/doc/mp-scratch.pdf)

It is done with a metapost script that you can find here : [metapost script for scratch algorithm](https://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/G/mp-scratch/src/)

My question: can we find something like that, but with tikz ? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Welcome! Better post relevant information in your question so it remains for others. I get an almost entirely blank page when I follow your link. (The framework of the page is there, but no content. Don't know what I'm meant to do with that.)

Comment: I can get the PDF, but it isn't in English, so doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: There is the very recent package `scratch`, which is based on TikZ and will be available with TeX Live 2017.

Comment: Why using tikz or metapost to write Scratch programs when Scratch does it very well and a copy screen in png can be inserted in the tex source?

Answer (score 1):

There is a(n other) new package which allows to write any kind of Scratch algorithm:
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scratchx